# Mapping a model from JSON give me a error when map int value

Tags: json, dart, flutter

Hi im trying to get values from JSOn but when I map a value that is a INT then flutter show that error and no return data :

```
flutter: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int'
```

This is my model :

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';


class Kits {

  final String country;
  final String franchise;
  final String type;
   String brand;
   String procedure;
   String setdesc;
   int traymaterialid;
   String traydesc;
   int referencia;
   String descart;
   int cantidad;
   int homologado;
   int bajopresu;
   DateTime insdate;


   Kits(this.country,this.franchise,this.type, this.brand, this.procedure,this.traydesc, this.traymaterialid);

  factory Kits.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic>  json) {
         return Kits(json['COUNTRY'], json['FRANCHISE'], json['TYPE'], json['BRAND'], json['PROCEDURE'], json['TRAYDESCRIPTION'], json['TRAYMATERIALID'] /* <-- INT*/ );
  }

}

class KitsData {

  static const url = 'http://app-smith.com/en/kits_API.php?email=miquel@winfor.es&macid=888&passwd=Wcz95f4UGkax5G';
  final JsonDecoder _decoder = new JsonDecoder();

    Future<List<Kits>> fetch(){    
  return http.get(url).then((http.Response response){
    final String jsonBody = response.body;
    //final statusCode = response.statusCode;

      /*if (statusCode < 200 || statusCode >= 300 || jsonBody == null){ 
        return List();
      }*/

      final kitsContainer = _decoder.convert(jsonBody);
      final List kitsItems = kitsContainer['kits'];

      return kitsItems.map( (kitsRaw) => new Kits.fromJson(kitsRaw) ).toList();

    });

  } 

}

class FetchDataException implements Exception {
  String _message;

  FetchDataException(this._message);

  String toString() {
    return "Exception: $_message";
  }
}
```

I don't understand why it's happen because fromJson is only getting the value that I pass the key then in my list I convert to String the value .

Fragment of JSON:

```
{"kits": [{"COUNTRY":"FR","FRANCHISE":"KNEE","TYPE":"LEGION","BRAND":"REVISION","PROCEDURE":"LEGION REVISION","SETDESCRIPTION":"LEGION REVISION - INSTRUMENTS","TRAYMATERIALID":"551820141LRC","TRAYDESCRIPTION":"INSTR LEGION REVISION","REFERENCIA":"71431722","DESCRIPCIONARTICULO":"LGN SCW LWDG TRL S3 5D X 10P","CANTIDAD":"1","HOMOLOGADO":"","BAJOPRESUPUESTO":"","INS_DATE":"2018-08-23 18:57:04"}
```

Comment: It very likely is **not** an int value. Ensure the value is **not** wrapped in `""` in the JSON string.

Comment: JSON added in my answer

Comment: All numeric values are inside quotes, so they are not transferred as `int` but as `String`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All numeric values are inside quotes, so they are not transferred as `int` but as `String`. The error message is correct. If you want them as `String` either ensure the values are not quoted, if you don't control that use `int.parse()` to convert them from `String` to `int`

Comment: Also note that the value for `TRAYMATERIALID` is `"551820141LRC"` which contains letters as well as digits. It is not an integer, nor will `int.parse` parse it as an integer.

Comment: I see. I missed that comment in the code. I saw `"REFERENCIA":"71431722"` but I couldn't find a single field with numeric value without quotes.